# twitter4j: 401 authentication credentials missing or incorrect (java)

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to get tweets from my java application,i tried this code it's work fine :

```
 ConfigurationBuilder cf=new ConfigurationBuilder() ;   cf.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXX")
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXX")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("XXX")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXX") ;
    TwitterFactory tf=new TwitterFactory(cf.build()) ;
            Twitter twitter=tf.getInstance() ;
            List<Status> status =twitter.getHomeTimeline();
            for(Status st : status) {
                System.out.println(st.getUser().getName()+"    "+st.getText());
            }
```

But when i'm trying to get stream data(tweet),it doesn't work.
this is the code:

```
StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + " : " + status.getText());
            }
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}
            public void onException(Exception ex) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        ConfigurationBuilder cf=new ConfigurationBuilder() ;
        cf.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXX")
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXX")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("XXX")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXX") ;
        TwitterStreamFactory tf = new TwitterStreamFactory(cf.build());
            TwitterStream twitterStream = tf.getInstance();
            twitterStream.addListener(listener);
            twitterStream.sample();
```

the error :

401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret
    \n\n\nError 401 Unauthorized

Comment: you may have to set the callback URL when registering your app in twitter

Comment: It work after setting the time in my machine ,thank you for reply